# How can i buid a query from a list using filters?

Tags: python, django, orm

Let's say in some database i have **People** who has this attributes:

- Name
- Age

If i wanted to get all the people that are called *Stuart* **or** *Steve* i could use Q objects:

```
qs = People.objects.filter(Q(name='Stuart') | Q(name='Steve'))
```

But, what if i'm receiving a list of *n* names? Example:
`['Bob, 'John','Rachel', 'Some other names that i don't know'...]`

**How could i build a query with those *n* unknown names on the list?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the simple solution is to use standart filter [__in=](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#in)

```
name_list = ['Bob', 'John', 'Rachel']
qs = People.objects.filter(name__in=name_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is `qs = People.objects.filter(name__in=['list of names'])` , there might be another efficient way also, I am not so sure.